# SELECT の AS と ORDER BY の AS について

Tags: mysql

MySQL で、SELECT と ORDER BY に同じ記述を書く際、ASを付与することで 重複記述を避けることは出来ますか？
また、もし重複記述を避けることが出来る場合、ASの影響方向は下記何れとなりますか？

- SELECT で設定した AS を ORDER BY で使用可能
- ORDER BY で設定した AS を SELECT で使用可能

---

1対多のコードがある時、

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  a.title,
  MAX(b.hoge_datetime),
  MIN(b.hoge_datetime)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY a.id
;
```

---

2機能追加したい

- 下記4カラムの最大値も取得
- 下記4カラムの最大値降順ソート

・aテーブル`x_time`カラム(必ず存在)
・aテーブル`z_time`カラム(NULL可能性あり)
・bテーブル`x_time`カラム(NULL可能性あり)
・bテーブル`z_time`カラム(NULL可能性あり)

---

下記コードを試してみてエラーは発生しなかったのですが、SELECT にも同じコードを書くのもどうかと思い、ASで何とかできないかと思ったので質問しました

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(
  a.`x_time`,
  IFNULL(a.`z_time`, a.`x_time`),
  IFNULL(MAX(b.`x_time`), a.`x_time`),
  IFNULL(MAX(b.`z_time`), a.`x_time`),
) DESC
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECTでエイリアスを指定して、別の部分で利用できます。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/select.html

> AS alias_name を使用して、select_expr　にエイリアスを指定できます。エイリアスは式のカラム名として使用され、GROUP BY、ORDER BY、または HAVING句で使用できます

SELECTでエイリアスをつけて`ORDER BY`で使用してください。